# Grantor Tax Information Letter

Tags: united-states, income-tax, trusts, form-1040, schedule-k-1

Why do some trusts issue a Sch K-1 for the beneficiaries, while others only a "Grantor tax information letter"?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the K-1 comes from trusts whose terms dictate distribution of earnings by the trust during the year. The K-1 information will flow right to the beneficiary tax return.

The second return you describe appears to retain its earnings, and let beneficiaries know about such activity as a reporting activity, but the trust itself would have filed the return, and paid the tax due from the trust itself.